# looping over shell commands in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have to restart systemd unit in my playbook and wait until service is active, so my "check and wait" logic must be as following in "pseudo-code":

```
for iterations=0; iterations < 10; iterations++ {
    status = systemctl is-active myservice
        if (status == active)
            break
        sleep 3s
    }
}
if status != active {
    failure: exit playbook
}
```

Seems like in ansible playbook i can iterate over the results of shell command but after looking into "loops" in documentation:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution
I couldn't find how to repeat command itself, based on output. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

There are [do-until](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) loops in Ansible:

```
- shell: systemctl is-active myservice
  register: results
  until: results | success
  retries: 10
  delay: 3
```

Comment: I  have the following error from your script:fatal: [10.209.47.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'results | success' failed. The error was: |failed expects a dictionary"}

Comment: What ansible version do you use? You can replace it with your own condition, like `until: results.rc == 0` or something.

Comment: version 2.1; current problem is: i have to specify number of retries from external variable and provide default if external var is not defined. I tried it like the following:- name: check results
    vars:
      val_retries: "{{ max_retries | default('10')  }}"
    shell: systemctl is-active marathon-haproxy
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find('active') == 0
    retries: '{{ val_retries }}'
    delay: 18 but it doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

I would use [service](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/service_module.html) or [systemd](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/systemd_module.html) and [wait_for](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html) modules for this purpose.